# Finding lowest value in List of tuple in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, list, tuples

I am trying to find lowest Item2 and return Item1 from tuple list, I tried to do it with List.Min but I couldn't get it right, here is my code.

```
Dim ahlist As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, Double))

    ahlist.Add(Tuple.Create("test1", 1.2))
    ahlist.Add(Tuple.Create("test2", 0.2))
    ahlist.Add(Tuple.Create("test3", 1.8))
```

Basically I want to find lowest number and return string (test2) in this case.

Comment: Look at the `Min` extension method.  You can provide a selector for the value to compare each item by.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a different data structure for this:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132329(v=vs.110).aspx
```

You add the key/value combinations.  The 0th one in the list is always the minimum key, making its an O(1) operation instead of O(n).  In this case, the key would be the Decimal, and the value would be the string.

Comment: Do we know that the `Double` values will be unique?

Comment: He's expecting to find a single element...so I'd say yes @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the order of the items for the comparison to be by the number first:

```
Dim ahlist As New List(Of Tuple(Of Double, String))

ahlist.Add(Tuple.Create(1.2, "test1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple fix from C# syntax to VB.net to @Aamir Nakehwa's answer.

```
Dim minValue As Double = ahlist.Min(Function(x) x.Item2)
Debug.Print(minValue.ToString)
```

Answer (score -1):

`ahlist.Min(x => x.Item2)`

Try this. I will return you the minimum value from your tuple list.
And hold it in any variable to use like below

`Dim minValue as Double = ahlist.Min(Function(x) x.Item2)`

Comment: It tells me 'x' element is not declared ;(

Comment: I was thinking along these lines but I was thinking that `Min` would return the `Tuple` rather than the `Double` value, thus allowing you to get the `String` from it.  As it returns the `Double` though, it doesn't solve the actual problem. By the way, `x => x.Item2` is C# syntax.  VB would be `Function(x) x.Item2`.

Comment: Thank you jmc, it works and returns me lowest double, but how can I get first value? (Item1).

Comment: Alright, I update my answer.
For the first value, use x.Item1